# creating language specific error pages in MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i have created language specific error pages using HTTP errors in IIS.

But have few issues. 
i have set language preference in IE.

```
<httpErrors defaultResponseMode="File" errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="error" path="error.htm"/>
</httpErrors>
```

So whenever i run my application error pages are getting displayed only in IE preferred language.so if i change application language. its not selecting application language only error pages are getting displayed in IE preferred language..

Answer (score 0):

you can add an Application_OnError on Global.asax and check if the error is a 404.

In this case you can overwrite the controller and action (i.e. ErrorController and NotFound action) passing a parameter of the application language

in the action you can use resource file to populate the model